# Capturing stdout from java.lang.reflect method invocation

Tags: java, reflection

I have an application that, among other things, runs Java methods via `java.lang.reflect`. It normally functions as normal; however, a user used it with one of their JARs, and it broke somewhat.

As you can see in the below code, I attempt to capture both `stdout` and `stdin` from the method. However, when the method is invoked, only the first line of what the method streams to `stdout` is actually captured.

Here's the relevant code. If you need to see more of the code, let me know, and I'll add some more:

```
String retVal = "";
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PrintStream origOut = System.out;
PrintStream origErr = System.err;

System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(err));

Exception myException = null;

try {
    Object myRetVal = null;
    myRetVal = m.invoke(obj, convertedMethodArguments);

    if (myRetVal != null)
        retVal = myRetVal.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    myException = e;
}

returnObj.addProperty("stdout", out.toString());
returnObj.addProperty("stderr", err.toString());
returnObj.addProperty("rv", retVal);
returnObj.addProperty("rt", m.getReturnType().toString());

if (myException != null && myException.getCause() != null)
    returnObj.addProperty("exception", myException.getCause().toString());
else
    returnObj.addProperty("exception", "");

System.setOut(origOut);
System.setErr(origErr);

System.out.print(new Gson().toJson(returnObj));

// TODO: remove, debug purposes only
// Should use normal stdout
try {
    System.out.println();
    m.invoke(obj, convertedMethodArguments);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

When I execute the above code, it only prints out the first line of `stdout`. However, at the bottom of the code block, I invoke the method again, but this time without any redirection, and I get all of the `stdout` from the method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT #1:** OK, get this. For fun, I commented-out the two lines where I redirect the default System streams (e.g. `System.setOut` and `System.setErr`). With these gone, I now expect all `stdout` to be written to the console directly when I run the app.

I added a message (e.g. `System.out.println("Testing...");`) at the very end of my code, so that it's the last thing that is executed. When I test the app, I get the first line of `stdout`, followed by my testing message, and THEN the rest of the `stdout`.

I have no clue what's going on here.

**EDIT #2:** Per @Titus's suggestion, I looked into whether or not the method I'm invoking is spinning off its own threads. Turns out, it is. Two threads are created, `AWT-AppKit` and `AWT-Shutdown`. The former thread seems to stay in `RUNNABLE` state, whereas the latter thread stays in the `TIMED_WAITING` state.

Over time, the `AWT-Shutdown` thread goes away, but the other one stays alive in its `RUNNABLE` state. Once my application exits, I believe the method I'm invoking also exits, and at that point the extra messages are displayed to the screen (which explains why I can't capture this bit of `STDOUT`).

What I don't understand is why this method won't terminate within my application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to flush the streams after you call the method.

Here is an example:

```
PrintStream outPR = new PrintStream(out);
System.setOut(outPR);
....
outPR.flush();
returnObj.addProperty("stdout", out.toString());
```

You can even do this:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
....
System.out.println();
returnObj.addProperty("stdout", out.toString());
```

The `PrintStream` is automatically flushed (if you use the constructor that I've used) when a `\n` (new line) is written to it.

Based on the edits to your question, it is possible that the method you're calling is creating new threads which means that it is possible that this new threads print to the console after the method returns.

If that is the case, you'll have to wait until this threads finish in order to get all the output.

Comment: I tried creating `PrintStream` objects and setting the System `out`/`err` to them, then flushing both `PrintStream` objects after invoking the method. It's still giving me trouble.

Comment: Although, your comment about new lines interests me. One thing I noticed is that the `stdout` is truncated after the first new line from `stdout`. If the `PrintStream` is flushed by that line, then my application wouldn't be able to capture the subsequent lines, correct? How can I keep the stream from flushing after new lines?

Comment: @kgrimes2 Actually, the `PrintStream` as you constructed it, will not flush the stream automatically. You'll have to use `new PrintStream(out, true)` to enable auto-flushing.

Comment: @kgrimes2 Flushing a stream only makes the stream forward all its buffered data, it doesn't remove any data.

Comment: Oh, okay, I understand flushing now, I think, thanks. I updated my post with something new I discovered. Does it help at all?

Comment: @kgrimes2 Based on your comment, it seems that the method you're calling starts a new thread and that new thread prints to the console after the method returns.

Comment: That's very possible. If that ends up being the case, do you know if there's a way to capture `stdout` from those new threads?

Comment: @kgrimes2 Yes, I guess you can. You could use `Thread.getThreads()` to get the active threads before and after you call the method and compare the two arrays to see if there were any new threads created. If the method indeed creates new threads, you could get the console output for as long as those threads keep running.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and see if I make progress. Would you like to update your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158542/discussion-between-kgrimes2-and-titus).